# Switch selection in runtime

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

Situation: There are 5 channel and they are assigned to any of 5 sensors(it can be changed runtime). Ex- channel 1 and 2 can be assigned to sensor 1.
However, I want that irrespective of assignment, all the sensor case in second switch get executed only once for the complete "For" loop cycle. 
I wrote following code but its not working. Can anyone tell the solution for this?

```
for(uChannel = 0; uChannel < 5; uChannel++) {
    switch(uChannel)
    { 
      case 0: sensor= calibrate.channel1;
       break;
      case 1: sensor= calibrate.channel2;
       break;
      case 2: sensor= calibrate.channel3;
       break;
      case 3: sensor= calibrate.channel4;
       break;
      case 4: sensor= calibrate.channel5;
       break;
      default:
    }

    switch(sensor)
     {
       case 1:     function(a,b);
    break;
   case 2:     function(c,b);
    break;
   case 3:     function(d,b);
    break;
   case 4:     function(e,b);
    break;
   case 5:     function(f,b);
    break;
   default                   
     }
```

}

Comment: Please post valid code. `default` cases in both of your `switch()` are not valid.

Comment: `I want that irrespective of assignment, all the sensor case in second switch get executed only once for the complete "For" loop` Why use the second switch then?

Comment: Please clarify your question. If you want the second `switch` to execute only once, move it outside `for` loop, simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can write function for second switch case and call it from every case of first switch For ex:

```
void executeSensor(int sensor){
     switch(sensor)
     {
       case 1:     function(a,b);
       break;
       case 2:     function(c,b);
       break;
       case 3:     function(d,b);
       break;
       case 4:     function(e,b);
       break;
      case 5:     function(f,b);
       break;
      default:
      break;              
     }
}
```

call in this way:

```
for(uChannel = 0; uChannel < 5; uChannel++) {
 switch(uChannel)
 { 
   case 0: sensor= calibrate.channel1;
    executeSensor(sensor)
    break;
   case 1: sensor= calibrate.channel2;
    executeSensor(sensor)
    break;
   case 2: sensor= calibrate.channel3;
   executeSensor(sensor)
    break;
   case 3: sensor= calibrate.channel4;
   executeSensor(sensor)
    break;
   case 4: sensor= calibrate.channel5;
   executeSensor(sensor)
    break;
   default:
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In above code there are two compilation error.

First you should fix that. Default case should be ended with `break` statement and `;`

```
for(uChannel = 0; uChannel < 5; uChannel++) {
    switch(uChannel)
    { 
      case 0: sensor= calibrate.channel1;
       break;
      case 1: sensor= calibrate.channel2;
       break;
      case 2: sensor= calibrate.channel3;
       break;
      case 3: sensor= calibrate.channel4;
       break;
      case 4: sensor= calibrate.channel5;
       break;
      default:
       break;
    }

    switch(sensor)
     {
       case 1:     function(a,b);
    break;
   case 2:     function(c,b);
    break;
   case 3:     function(d,b);
    break;
   case 4:     function(e,b);
    break;
   case 5:     function(f,b);
    break;
   default:
     break;              
     }

  }
```